# Porting AES decryption from CryptoJS to Php

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric

I am trying to convert a AES decryption function from JavaScript into PHP script. Ignoring the indentation for easy to read.

```
var enc = 'EK/tvL3RsjOY1j82ILXv7W10bEU83JeaiBhlLmcZIrk=';

var key = 'FSHcT+sfRO/siok2ooweuA==' ;

var y = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ciphertext:     CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(enc)}, 
CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key), 
{iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("2323232323232323")});

var dec = y.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

In the PHP I have tried

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(16, '2323232323232323'); 

$enc = 'EK/tvL3RsjOY1j82ILXv7W10bEU83JeaiBhlLmcZIrk=';

$key = 'FSHcT+sfRO/siok2ooweuA==' ;

$dec = rtrim((mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $enc, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv)), "\0\3");
```

In Javascript decrypting working fine but when I execute the PHP it gives me strange charecters.

Comment: Define *"strange charecters"*.

Comment: Anything that is not the actual output as it is meant to be.

Comment: PHP is using ASCII, while Javascript is using UTF-8. Different encoding, isn't it ?

Comment: `echo $dec;` what does that show you?

Comment: jsº—àžd^¶Ï—6OÀÆúË¥îFTqó\°ª=»±Ê%è»5eÝq!M

Comment: different everytime page is loaded

Comment: which... is... normal. What were you expecting?

Comment: Actual output "I want to decode this"

Answer (score 5):

#### Warning: This is Weak Cryptography

- You're using CBC mode with a constant IV of null bytes (the IV should be randomly generated for each message).
- You're [not authenticating your ciphertext](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly).
- Naive use of `rtrim()` exposes your application to [padding oracle attacks](http://robertheaton.com/2013/07/29/padding-oracle-attack/), which wouldn't be a problem if you were following an Encrypt Then MAC construction.

#### The Actual Bugs in Your Code

```
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv(16, '00000000000000000000000000000000');
```

That's not how this function is meant to be used.

```
string mcrypt_create_iv(int $length, int $source);
```

For example: `mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);` will generate 16 bytes of random data from `/dev/urandom`. It looks like you want `str_repeat("\0", 16)` here, but as I said above, this is a horrible idea.

You also didn't `base64_decode()` the key.

---

I really hope you aren't deploying this code anywhere.

Recommended reading: [Write crypto code! Don't publish it!](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/75204435608/write-crypto-code-dont-publish-it) by Talyor Hornby.

Also, if you can [avoid using mcrypt](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong), you'll find yourself a lot happier.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `mcrypt` extension (wich is implemented in C), so you don't need to port JS code.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

Comment: mcrypt is used if i am not wrong. not entirely porting rather looking at same output from different type of web form.

Comment: So, whats the problem?

Comment: problem is the output which I am mentioning at the bottom

Comment: oh, now I see.. Then check the parameters, maybe you have to do the steps with base64 and so on too.. not sure actually, read the docs )

Comment: I'm not sure that answer really sheds any light on this situation. Also, [mcrypt sucks, please stop using it](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong).